# Android Maps - how to automatically center the map to the user's current location?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have a Google Maps Activity, and I want the camera to center and zoom in on the user as soon as the map opens/the blue dot appears, so that the user doesn't have to press the "center button" and I don't have to hardcode the position of the map camera.
I've found a lot of code examples that are 5-6 years old so none of them work anymore.
Is it even possible to get the current user location (lat. and long.) anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try this:

```
private void centerOnMyLocation() {

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    location = map.getMyLocation();

    if (location != null) {
        myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
    }
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation,
            Constants.MAP_ZOOM));
}
```

Update the properties name and call this code to center on the current user's location.

If you already have the current position, just call this fuction:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation,
                Constants.MAP_ZOOM));
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct, concise answer, IMHO.

Comment: getMyLocation() is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need a LatLngBounds object, this is necessary so that you can define the positions that will bound the map.

Then, you will need define a width and a height of your device, which is very simple.

Just follow the code below

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
//Insert your location
builder.include(location1);
builder.include(location2);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

//Get the width and height of the device's screen
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = (int) ((getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) * 0.85);
int padding = (int) (width * 0.15);

//Centralize the markers
yourMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));
```

Comment: int height = (int) ((getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) * 0.70);  this works